# Border gone from table?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, css-tables

For some reason, one of the inside borders disappears on my table whenever I change the default height with some CSS.

HTML:

```
<table class="event">
  <tr>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>2009-6-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>2009-6-8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Vail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.event
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 33%;
  height: 300px;
}

table.event td
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Here's what it currently looks like

[http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/394/whatv.png http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/394/whatv.png](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/394/whatv.png)

Anybody have any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: What browser is this happening in?

Comment: have you made sure that your cache is cleared out?  Maybe hit ctrl + F5 to reload and see if that corrects.... just worked fine for me in IE and Firefox...

Comment: The image link is now dead making the question less clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take your code and put it directly in a blank html page, does it work? I am wondering if there is something outside causing it, perhapes in a different CSS (just guessing).

I pulled this open in FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome, IE6-7 and 8 and could not replicate it.

Even with/without out the border-collapse i get the same results.

Comment: Yes, it works with a completely blank HTML page and CSS. Thanks for offering this troubleshooting method. There must be something else affecting it.

Comment: No problem, sorry can't help you much more without seeing your entire code base.

Comment: Yes, I'll look through the rest of it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you load the firebug addin to Firefox and then select&inspect the element(s) that aren't styled as you expect, it will show what styles are used and over-written by others.

Comment: Just solved it, I was zoomed out a little bit in Firefox. Dang, I feel dumb.

Comment: Oh my! I have done that before, glad you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the problem. Jeez, I feel like an idiot. The reason this was happening was because I was "zoomed out" a little bit in Firefox. The scaling got rid of one of the inside borders.

Thanks to all for the help, It was Jason Heine's idea that eventually lead to me figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine for me in firefox and ie7.  Are you changing the height with javascript or something else, or just within the editor?  However, you could try getting rid of border-collapse.

Comment: No, I am not changing anything with JS.

Comment: Is it possible that you are referencing another stylesheet after the fact or that you made another style for the table later on in your css that could be causing it?